# Can't find jQuery on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```

Changed webpack environment

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    noUiSlider: 'nouislider'
  })
)
```

And made npm install -save jquery

I am trying even:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
debugger
```

...and nothing. I tried everything, but in Chrome console always:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: i guess `jquery` path is wrong, you could try `$: 'jquery/src/jquery', jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery', ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" of course works, but I need to use webpaker.

I resolved it so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
...
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and *config\webpack\environment.js*

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    noUiSlider: 'nouislider'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0):

set this jquery min js

```
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"
```